# CUDA_HOME path for Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, cudnn

The [Tensorflow linux installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux) say:

> Ensure that you create the CUDA_HOME environment variable as described
>   in the NVIDIA documentation.

I cannot find any mention of CUDA_HOME in the NVIDIA instructions for cuDNN v6 or in the [NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit install instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#introduction). Does anyone know how this variable should be set on linux?

Comment: If you installed CUDA in `/usr/local` then in `.bashrc` file enter `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @Zindarod that is definitely part of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH step, which is the step before the question about CUDA_HOME, but that doesn't address the question about CUDA_HOME.

Answer (score 42):

Run the following command in the terminal:

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-X.X
```

Where you replace X.X by the first two digits of your version number (can be found out e.g. via `nvcc --version`).

Comment: This should probably be updated to cuda-9.0 now that the recommended installation is version 9.0.

Comment: Or just use `export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda` if you have a symlink to the newest version

Comment: I note that the `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package on Ubuntu 20.04 creates a folder `/usr/lib/cuda` which contains `bin`, `include` etc. So presumably `CUDA_HOME` should in this case be set to /usr/lib/cuda?

Comment: @user2023370 , I have the same doubt. did you figure this out in the end?

Comment: @desmond13 Alas no. I don't find that this variable is properly documented by NVIDIA.

Comment: if install cudatoolkit via anaconda , can try: `export CUDA_HOME=$CONDA_PREFIX/bin/`

Comment: If installed via the official Nvidia CUDA Toolkit installer, there will be multiple locations: `/usr/local/cuda/`, `/usr/local/cuda-X` (X - major version) and `/usr/local/cuda-X.Y` (Y - minor version). All are connected to each other via symlinks. If you want to use the latest version (in case you have multiple), you eather go with `cuda` or `cuda-X.Y`.

Answer (score 13):

If using anaconda to install, the following would apply:

```
export CUDA_HOME=$CONDA_PREFIX
```

You can add this to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` to have this environment variable persist between sessions. To apply this change in the bash file to your current session run: `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile`

Verify this by issuing an `echo $CUDA_HOME` command.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this issue whilst trying to install NVIDIAs Kaolin. As @user2023370 said the nvidia-cuda-toolkit creates a bunch of folders and I can confirm that it will set CUDA_HOME. This circumvents the need to set the variable with export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-X.X

tldr; install nvidia-cuda-toolkit to set CUDA_HOME

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions

or for the latest version of cuda
put  export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.6/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}} at the end of your bashrc.

It should work